# is there any way to set flutter first page as user favorite?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that is working fine and I want to add an option in settings page that allows user to choose his own favorite starting page , for example if he use the B.dart most of the time then the first screen that open through app would be B.dart and some other pages be available to choose , can anyone give me a hint? thanks

Comment: In setting user have a option to set any page as starting page ya need to check user everytime which page visit mostly and navigate automatically to most visited screen??

Comment: thanks for your answer . for example like drop down with 3 items which are the pages and user can select between them

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Change your MyApp to StatefulWidget from StatelessWidget. Before runApp() function, fetch selection data from shared preferences and send it to MyApp state. If data is null, then navigate to default page, if not null, navigate to the screen accordingly.

Pseudo code for my explanation:

```
// main class
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
var instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var page = instance.getString("favorite_page");
runApp(MyApp(favoritePage: page));
}
```

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.favoritePage}) : super(key: key);

  final String favoritePage;

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: widget.favoritePage == "condition" ? HomeView() : FavoriteView(),
    );
  }
}
```